# TypeScript not inferring specific type

Tags: typescript

In the code below, TypeScript gives an error on the `map` function:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.

But `propertyValue` in that context is `string[]`, because `propertyName` is `'chapters'`. Why doesn't TypeScript know that?

```js
interface Book {
  title: string;
  chapters: string[];
}

const setBookProperty = <K extends keyof Book>(propertyName: K, propertyValue: Book[K]) => ({
  payload: { propertyName, propertyValue },
});

const reducer = (action: ReturnType<typeof setBookProperty>) => {
  switch (action.payload.propertyName) {
    case 'chapters': {
      const x = action.payload.propertyValue.map(s => s === 'Chapter 1');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `ReturnType<typeof setBookProperty>` is evaluated once as the type for `action` and the type it returns doesn't maintain any pairing between `propertyName` and `propertyValue`.  The initial type for `action` is `payload: {
        propertyName: "title" | "chapters";
        propertyValue: string | string[];
    };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReturnType<typeof setBookProperty>` is evaluated once as the type for `action` and the type it returns doesn't maintain any pairing between `propertyName` and `propertyValue`. Instead it is the union for all possible values of each, without any understanding that one depends on the other.

If you inspect the type of `action`, you'll see that it is:

```
{
    payload: {
        propertyName: "title" | "chapters";
        propertyValue: string | string[];
    };
}
```

Seeing that, you can understand how narrowing one won't narrow the other.

In order to know the value of one based on the other, the type of your action needs to be a union of all valid pairings.  This does require more code, but it will get you the result that you want.

Define a generic action which gives the pairing for a specific key

```
type ActionSpecific<K extends keyof Book> = {
    payload: {
        propertyName: K,
        propertyValue: Book[K]
    }
}
```

Use a mapping to get the union for all keys.  In this case it is trivial since we only have two keys.

```
type ActionMap = {
    [K in keyof Book]: ActionSpecific<K>
}

type ActionUnion = ActionMap[keyof Book]
```

`ActionUnion` resolves to `ActionSpecific<"title"> | ActionSpecific<"chapters">` so it maintains the pairing.  If you were to type `ActionSpecific<keyof Book>` instead you would get the same bad type as before where the pairing is lost.

(Optional) Declare the return type of `setBookProperty` as `ActionSpecific<K>`

```
const setBookProperty = <K extends keyof Book>(propertyName: K, propertyValue: Book[K]): ActionSpecific<K> => ({
    payload: { propertyName, propertyValue },
});
```

Use `ActionUnion` as the type for your reducer function's `action`, and the `switch` will be able to discriminate between members of the union.

```
const reducer = (action: ActionUnion) => {
    switch (action.payload.propertyName) {
        case 'chapters': {
            const x = action.payload.propertyValue.map(s => s === 'Chapter 1');
        }
    }
};
```